# What's the run-time complexity of the following code

Tags: java, time-complexity

What's the run-time complexity of the following code

```
public void foo (int n, int m)
{
   int i = m;
   while (i > 100)
      i = i/3;
   for (int k=i ; k>=0; k--)
   {
      for (int j=1; j<n; j*=2)
         System.out.print(k + "\t" + j);
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

I think it's `O(log n)`, But I'm not sure about the first for loop. It runs maximum 100 times, but log n in every iteration.

EDIT: It's not a duplicated of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm) since I know how to find time complexity, but this specific case was a bit tricky so I asked only about this one, I didn't ask how to find time complexity in general. Like the fact that I know how to play football in general, doesn't mean I can kick like messi, maybe I need some explanation on how to do it, but I don't need explanation of what is football etc.

Comment: You need to think that the number 100 would be an infinite number of iterations.

Answer (score 2):

First loop is 0(log m), as iterations give i the values m/3, m/9, m/27...

The inner loop (on j) executes its body log n times, and itself is executed at most 100 times

So the complexity is O(log(m)) + O(log(n))

Comment: This is what I thought, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the first loop first:

```
int i = m;
while (i > 100)
   i = i/3;
```

Can be described as `T(i) = O(1) + T(i/3)`, since you're doing some const work (condition comparison etc.) and then reiterating the loop with a value smaller by a third. If we'll expand it by recursion, we'll get:

```
T(i) = O(1) + T(i/3)
     = O(1) + O(1) + T(i/3/3) = 2*O(1) + T(i/9)
     = 2*O(1) + O(1) + T(i/9/3) = 3*O(1) + T(i/27)
     = ... = n*O(1) + T(i/3^n)
```

The last statement being for the n-th iteration. Now, the loop would stop `i/3^n <= 100` which means when `n = log3(i/100)`. So you'll do `log(i)` operations, which means the first loop's complexity is `O(log(i))`. (note that you've set i=m so this is basically `O(log(m))`).

Now let's look at the second loop:

```
for (int k=i ; k>=0; k--) {
   for (int j=1; j<n; j*=2)
      System.out.print(k + "\t" + j);
   System.out.println();
}
```

The inner loop can be described as `T(n) = O(1) + T(2*n)`. Let's expand:

```
T(j) = O(1) + T(2j) = O(1) + O(1) + T(2*2j) = 2*O(1) + T(4j)
     = 2*O(1) + O(1) + T(2*4j) = 3*O(1) + T(8j)
     = ... = l*O(1) + T((2^l)*j)
```

Again, the last one being for the l-th iteration. So you'll stop once `(2^l)*j = n`, which means when `j=log(n)`. So the inner loop complexity is `O(log(n))`.

Now let's look at the outer loop. It could be described as `T(k) = O(log(n)) + T(k-1)`. Let's expand:

```
T(k) = O(log(n)) + T(k-1) = O(log(n)) + O(log(n)) + T(k-1-1) = 2*O(log(n)) + T(k-2)
```

By this point, I'm sure you can see that by the l-th iteration you'll have `l*O(log(n)) + T(k-l)`. You'll stop once `k-l < 0` so when `k=l` and so the complexity is `O(k*log(n))`.

But what is `k`? Well, `k` is basically set to the value of `i` which is `m` chopped down `log3` times. So you'll be doing `log(n)` work for `log(m)` times. So your complexity is `O(log(m)*log(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you got it right it O(log(n))+O(log(m)) which is going to be O(log(n*m)) since

- complexity of first loop is O(log(m))
- the second loop has complexity
  of O(log(n))
- Complexity ~ a * log(n)+b * log(m)
- min(a,b) (log(n)+log(m)) < a * log(n)+b * log(m) < max(a,b) (log(n)+log(m))
- min(a,b)  < [a * log(n)+b * log(m)]/[(log(n*m))] < max(a,b)

so you can say that your expression is Order of log(n*m)

Answer (score -1):

Since it contains 2 nested loops, and both operate on log n terms, it's

O(log m)                   = while loop +

O(log m * (log n))         = for loop

Base of log as 2 and 3 can be omitted.

So it comes to log mn (Max of these)

Comment: The outer loop is not `O(log(m))`, it's constant (`i` <= 100 regardless of `m`).